# Open Babel C++ API Why cannot be their custom iterators used directly as an argument to a function?

Tags: c++, iterator, type-conversion

In the Open Babel library, there are defined many iterator objects for OBMol class, like [OBMolAtomiter](http://openbabel.org/dev-api/classOpenBabel_1_1OBMolAtomIter.shtml). On the linked page, there is following code sample illustrating the usage.

```
  #include <openbabel/obiter.h>
  #include <openbabel/mol.h>

  OpenBabel::OBMol mol;
  double exactMass = 0.0;
  FOR_ATOMS_OF_MOL(a, mol)
  {
     // The variable a behaves like OBAtom* when used with -> and * but
     // but needs to be explicitly converted when appearing as a parameter
     // in a function call - use &*a

     exactMass +=  a->GetExactMass();
  }
```

(`FOR_ATOMS_OF_MOL(a, mol)` expands into a for cycle, `a` is declared to be of the iterator type. `mol` is an existing molecule to iterate over)

I want to ask, why the `&*p` thing described in the comment is necessary. The behavior when I pass the iterator to a function that expects pointer is that the the code compiles, but the program behaves strangely.

I tried to Google for it, I found the page about [iterator_traits](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iterator_traits.html), is it anyhow related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOR_ATOMS_OF_MOL(a, mol)` macro constructs `a` of type `OBMolAtomIter`. To return `OBAtom`s, the `*` and `->` operators have been overloaded. That is why `a` cannot be transmitted directly to functions, but `*a` and `a->` behave as if `a` was an `OBAtom *`.

http://openbabel.org/api/2.2.0/classOpenBabel_1_1OBMolAtomIter.shtml

Comment: I am sorry for this question. I somehow thought that STL iterators can be casted to "compatible" pointer types and wondered why the Babel ones cannot. Now I see iterators cannot be so casted.

Comment: My program behaved strange because it IS possible to cast the OBMolAtomiter object to an int, because it defines conversion to bool. Which is what had beed happening, because the function I called is overloaded to accept both OBAtom* and int.